# How to type hint pandas.NA as a possible output

Tags: python, pandas, nan, type-hinting, python-typing

I have Pandas lambda function which I use with [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply).

This function will output a dictionary with string keys and values that are either strings or [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na).

When I try to type hint the function I get an error:

```py
def _the_function(x: str) -> dict[str, str | pd.NA]:
    ...
```

```
ERROR: Expected class type but received "NAType"
```

How can I tell it of the possible `pd.NA` value without having to import numpy and using its `NaN` type hint? My project has no need to import numpy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `pandas.NA` is not a **type**. It is an **instance** (a singleton in fact) of the [`NAType`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/missing.pyx#L382) class in Pandas. You need to use **classes** in type annotations.* More precisely, annotations must be made with instances of `type` (typically called *classes*) or special typing constructs like `Union` or generics.

You can fix this by importing and using that class in the type annotation:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas._libs.missing import NAType
...

def _the_function(x: str) -> dict[str, str | NAType]:
    return {"foo": pd.NA}  # example to show annotations are correct
```

Running `mypy` over that code shows no errors.

The only problem is that `_libs` is a non-public module (as denoted by its name starting with `_`). This may be due to the `NA` singleton still being considered experimental. I don't know. But importing from non-public modules is generally discouraged. I searched through the Pandas (and pandas-stubs) source and found no public re-import of the `NAType` class, so I see no other way around it.

If `NA` is still experimental, I suppose you know the risk you are taking when relying on it in your functions, so importing its class should not make much of a difference to you.

Hope this helps.

---

** Confusion can arise because Python allows using `None` in type annotations, even though strictly speaking it is also an object (also a singleton) of the `NoneType` class. But the good people working on type hints in Python decided to still allow `None` as a special case for convenience, even though it is not exactly consistent. As far as I know, that is the **only** such exception.*